# Can you have one Style and put all CSS code inside?

Tags: html, css

Im new to HTML and I am just doing some CSS tasks to make my website look sleek, I have made different styles for each css code all. For example for a paragraph with an ID has its own style, while another paragraph with another different ID has it's own style.

Can I merge them all together in one style? I am trying to get as many marks as I can for professional code manner.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes you can.**

If both the same styles use a `class name` and apply it for both. And if there is a slight difference between them you can use a class for the common rules and use IDs or other methods of selectors to apply specific styles.

*The following is an example for what I explained.*

```css
.para {
  background-color: #eee;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}

#first {
  color: red;
  font-size: 17px;
}

#second {
  color: blue;
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<p class="para" id="first">quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore</p>

<p class="para" id="second">quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore</p>
```

Comment: @Ziggler I think someone decided to downvote the question and all its answers just because! anyway maybe I should have provide some examples to my answer to keep things clear.

Comment: Yes I also noticed someone simply downvoted all answers before I posted mine.. but personally I like your reply. It gives idea what the person has to do .. it directs them in correct path...

Comment: @Ziggler thank you. I edited it with a code example for more clarity. I hope it helps

Comment: Thats good Doha... Unlike others I appreciate your willingness to help others

Answer (score 0):

Create a style like below which can be used for all paragraph using class

```
.apppara 
{
   font-size: 11.5px;
}
```

You can use like below

```
<p class="apppara">XXX</p>
```

Then you can create styles like below for individual ids

```
#paraname {    
    color: red;
}
```

You can use like below

```
<p class="apppara" id="paraname">XXX</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:

1.) Use classes - that way you can apply *one* style / i.e. CSS rule to many elements.

2.) Also use combined and nested CSS selectors for rules in your stylesheet - that way you can define rules (for classes or tags) that only apply in certain situations, for example when an element with a certain class is inside a particular parent element.

3.) Look into CSS preprocessors like LESS and SASS - they make combining selectors and reuse of elements pretty easy.